# Read and Import Excel File into DataSet using C# in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need upload Excel File and then read and import its data into DataTable using C# in ASP.Net Web Application.

The imported Excel File data is then displayed in ASP.Net GridView control.

I'm using the code below but I have problem with column "AV" on the Excel File

The column "AV" contains these values

[image]

But in gridview output I have

[image]

**In gridview output I don't have the numbers of Excel file source, but only "-" values**

Any suggestion?

```
    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            Master.PleaseWait();
            string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            string Extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            string FolderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderPath"];
            string FilePath = Server.MapPath(FolderPath + FileName);
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(FilePath);
            Import_To_Grid(FilePath, Extension, rbHDR.SelectedItem.Text);
        }
    }

    private void Import_To_Grid(string FilePath, string Extension, string isHDR)
    {
        string conStr = "";

        switch (Extension)
        {
            case ".xls":
                conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                break;

            case ".xlsx": 
                conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
                break;
        }

        conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath, isHDR);
        OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
        OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;
        connExcel.Open();
        DataTable dtExcelSchema;
        dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        connExcel.Close();

        connExcel.Open();
        cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From[" + SheetName + "]";
        oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
        oda.Fill(dt);
        connExcel.Close();

        GridView1.Caption = Path.GetFileName(FilePath);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: "I have problem with column "AV" " It would be very kind of you to tell us what kind of problem do you have. Does it  have a wrong font colour?

Comment: @Serge His question shows that the AV column should contain numbers in some rows, but it does not in his results.

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see what gets loaded into the `DataTable`?

Comment: @Serge thanks for reply. on the gridview I don't have the numbers of excel file source,  but only "-" values

Comment: @EdwardSheriffCurtis Do you have any error? what is the problem?

Comment: @Serge No error... the numerical value of the AV column is not reported correctly in the gridview

Comment: @JackA. In the debug no problems...

Comment: @EdwardSheriffCurtis why you don' t try this algorithm https://www.csharp-console-examples.com/general/c-read-excel-file-into-datatable/   Just diefine AV column as a string, after loading you can convert it.